How to move unallocated space in a partition to a different partition
I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04 The windows partition needs more space.  I used GParted to shrink the Ubuntu partition /dev/sda6 by 30 GB and then moved the resulting unallocated space it to the left of /dev/sda6 (see below), but now I can't I can't move the unallocated space to the left of dev/sda3 (the move/resize option is grayed out) so that it is adjacent to /dev/sda2 for expansion of /dev/sda2 into the unallocated space. I also tried moving /dev/sda3 to the right, but there is no space to move it on the slider.  Is the problem that the unallocated space in a separate partition (subpartition) from the sda2 partition? How can I get the unallocated space next to sda2 to expand it?


MSDOS partitioning has a max of four primary partitions, which you have (the extended partition counts as a primary). Maybe edit (if gui can't do the extended change, use a tool like fdisk to allow sector start/end changes) the start of the extended to the same sector as the start of sda6 so the unallocated space is available to the other primaries, move sda3 right, then expand sda2

Your solution sounds plausible, but fdisk doesn't have an option to change the start sector of a partition.  Despite the search result as follows:It appears that the start sector can only be set when adding a new partiton with fdisk and as you pointed out, I'm maxed out (Thanks Microsoft!)
